# How to group array of objects to separate arrays by object value?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Example:

```
array  = [{name:'Anna'}, {name:'Bob'}, {name:'Joe'}, {name:'Anna'}]
```

I need to group this array by name to get separate arrays like:

```
array 1 = [{name:'Anna'}, {name:'Anna'}]
array 2 = [{name:'Joe'}]
array 3 = [{name:'Bob'}]
```

Got no idea how to perfom this. Thanks!

Comment: That's grouping, not _sorting_

Comment: Thats not sorting.  That is filtering.  Sorting means all contents of 1 bucket.  You want to filter the contents of 1 bucket into others.  You would need to develop a Set of values, which correlates to the number of buckets.  Filter would be run a bunch of times, but you can create a more optimal solution then calling that command N time

Comment: @hindmost, sort of ...

Comment: More importantly, where is your attempt. What did you try?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> You mean to group the items by name I think, and not to sort them.

If this is what you want, you can create an intermediate dictionary with [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), whose keys are the names and the values are arrays grouping all object with the same name.

Then use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to enumerate this dictionary and return all groups:

```js
const arr = [{name:'Anna', hello: 1}, {name:'Bob'}, {name:'Joe'}, {name:'Anna'}];

const result = Object.values(arr.reduce((acc, x) => {
  acc[x.name] = [...(acc[x.name] || []), x ];
  return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I started doing myself, but the function was much much bigger than yours. Learned a lot from your example, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Group your array by `name` first and then get the object values. You can use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) for this purpose

```js
var array  = [{name:'Anna'}, {name:'Bob'}, {name:'Joe'}, {name:'Anna'}];

const res = array.reduce((acc, item) => {
   if (acc[item.name]) {
      acc[item.name] = [...acc[item.name], item];
   } else {
      acc[item.name] = [item];
   }
   return acc;
}, {});

console.log(Object.values(res));
```

Answer (score 0):

just convert to object based on value using reduce:

```
const test = array.reduce((acc, el) => {
  if (!acc[el.name]) {
    return {
       ...acc,
       [el.name]: [el]
    }
  }
  return {
    ...acc,
    [el.name]: [...acc[el.name], el]
  }
}, {});
```

you got an object with fields, each fields contains requested array of elements